# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Form Post

Tags: asp.net, forms, powershell

I'm trying to automate submitting a web form (mainly as an exercise for learning Powershell better).

The first thing I did was use Fiddler2 to see what EXACT webform fields (and respective values) are sent (using a regular web browser to submit the data).

Then, I recreated ALL possible fields and values I saw in Fiddler's WebForm tab in my Powershell script below; I included __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION (and their values I grabbed from the start of the websession).  I included fields that have no values (identical to what I saw in fiddler).  I even included the submit button (since I saw that in Fiddler too).

Unfortunately, after I POST all fields using my script; when I look at $response.rawcontent (shown in script below), it's still on the same webpage I started with.  If I submit the form using my web browser, it updates the page with new information.  I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong or missing.  I originally tried POSTing the form without any of the fields that start with __  However, that didn't work.

PS:  When submitting the form via a web browser, I have two more fields that are greyed out (and filled in for me with my name and email address).  However, interestingly, I dont see these two fields in Fiddler.  I'm guessing they may be submitted via __VIEWSTATE or __EVENTVALIDATION encoded data?

Thank you so much for helping me!

```
$UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)'
$r=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://website.com/RTR/xl/requestform.aspx' -UseDefaultCredentials -SessionVariable RequestForm

$fields = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://website.com/RTR/xl/requestform.aspx' -WebSession $RequestForm | select -ExpandProperty inputfields | select name, value

$viewstate = $fields | ?{$_.name -match "VIEWSTATE"} | select -ExpandProperty value
$eventvalidation = $fields | ?{$_.name -match "EVENTVALIDATION"} | select -ExpandProperty value

#Same exact fields and values seen in Fiddler; even in the same order:    
$form.Fields["__EVENTTARGET"] = ""
$form.Fields["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
$form.Fields["__VIEWSTATE"] = $viewstate
$form.Fields["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = $eventvalidation
$form.Fields["xl$phone"] = "917-471-6784""
$form.Fields["xl$form$Submit"] = "Submit"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://website.com/RTR/xl/requestform.aspx' -WebSession $RequestForm -Method POST -Body $form.Fields -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$response.rawcontent | out-file $home\response.html
```

Comment: You should consider using Fiddler's "Raw" tab to make sure there's not a header you're missing.  Also, if the html form names are literally `xl$phone` then keep in mind that in a double quoted string phone will look for a variable named `$phone`.  It likely won't exist and your field name will be just "xl".  So use single quoted strings instead e.g. `'xl$phone'`.  Finally, compare the "raw" tab contents in Fiddler for your PowerShell invocation with the "raw" contents for the manual invocation.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the problem.  I needed to use literal $ sign in the field names; exactly how I saw them in fiddler webform fields.  It works now.  Thanks.

Comment: Added an official answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

If the html form names are literally `xl$phone` then keep in mind that in a double quoted string phone will look for a variable named $phone. It likely won't exist and your field name will be just "xl". So use single quoted strings instead e.g. `'xl$phone'`.